# SQL server PIVOT with row grouping

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table that looks like this:

### **Table**

```
+------+----------+
| CODE | DATE     |
+======+==========+
|  A   | 6/30/14  |
|  A   | 3/31/14  |
|  A   | 12/31/13 |
|  A   | 9/30/13  |
|  B   | 5/31/14  |
|  B   | 2/28/14  |
|  B   | 11/30/13 |
|  B   | 8/31/14  |
|  C   | 6/27/14  |
|  C   | 3/28/14  |
|  C   | 12/27/13 |
|  C   | 9/27/13  |
+------+----------+
```

I need the output to look like this:

### **Expected Output**

```
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| CODE  |  DATE_1   | DATE_2   |  DATE_3   |  DATE_4  |
+=======+===========+==========+===========+==========+
|  A    |  6/30/14  | 3/31/14  | 12/31/13  | 9/30/13  |
|  B    |  5/31/14  | 2/28/14  | 11/30/13  | 8/31/14  |
|  C    |  6/27/14  | 3/28/14  | 12/27/13  | 9/27/13  |
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Each code value (A, B, C) is displayed 4 times, so the DATE_1, DATE_2, DATE_3, and DATE_4 fields do not change. Can someone help??

Comment: What's the order of the four dates? Pivot them only by physical order?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Pivot with Dynamic Fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902626/sql-server-pivot-with-dynamic-fields)

Comment: Almost any PIVOT/UNPIVOT question is a duplicate. OP, please look into some examples online (there are plenty incl on SO), and try it yourself at least. If you have problems with your query, post what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `PIVOT` can achieve this.

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT code,
[1] AS DATE_1,
[2] AS DATE_2,
[3] AS DATE_3,
[4] AS DATE_4
FROM
(
  SELECT code, dt, 
  row_number() over 
  (
     partition by code 
     ORDER BY code
  ) rn
  FROM tbl
) t
PIVOT 
(
  MIN (dt) FOR rn IN 
  (
     [1], [2], [3], [4]
  )
) pvt
```

### **[FIND FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92946/34)**

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful and revealed a lot about how to manipulate the pivot and partition by code!